# Changing return type with JSON annotations

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I have the following hibernate class

```
@Entity
class A {
    List<String> list;

    ...

    List<String> getList();
}
```

After hibernate instantiation and Jackson serialization, the `getList()` method is serialized as `org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag`.
During deserialization back I get the following exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy...`

If i'm replacing the serialized string (with simple String.replaceAll...) from `org....PersistentBag` to a `java....List` type, the object gets deserialized well as needed.

Same for hibernate's PersistentSet and java's HashSet.

Any idea how I can solve this without replacing the string?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here, but Jackson always serializes lists to arrays. Be a bit more clear on what you are doing and what you are doing it with

Comment: I'm using hibernate and ObjectsMapper to serialize this object into JSON. Because hibernate is using PersistentBag instead of List, I'd like to force JSON to think its a List, and not any other hibernate wrapper/object.

Comment: I've revised my question to make it more clean

Comment: You can try with `@JsonDeserialize(as = ArrayList.class) List<String> list;` or `@JsoSerialize(as = ArrayList.class) List<String> list;`.

Comment: @Franjavi, still doesn't work. After serialization it still remains serialized as PersistentBag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for `Set` serialized as `PersistentSet`.

I solved it using Mixin and custom deserializer for `Set`, deserializing `PersistentSet` as `HashSet`.

The same approach should work for `List` - `PersistentBag`.

SetMixin:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonDeserialize(using = SetDeserializer.class)
public abstract class SetMixin {

    @JsonCreator
    public SetMixin(Set<?> s) {
    }
}
```

SetDeserializer:

```
public class SetDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Set> {

    @Override
    public Set deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jp);
        Set<Object> resultSet = new HashSet<>();
        if (node != null) {
            if (node instanceof ArrayNode) {
                ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) node;
                Iterator<JsonNode> nodeIterator = arrayNode.iterator();
                while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
                    JsonNode elementNode = nodeIterator.next();
                    resultSet.add(mapper.readValue(elementNode.toString(), Object.class));
                }
            } else {
                resultSet.add(mapper.readValue(node.toString(), Object.class));
            }
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Add SetMixin to ObjectMapper:

```
mapper.addMixIn(Set.class, SetMixin.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use a generic converter, that converts the hibernate internal list to arraylist before serialising. At the time of de-serialising we get an arraylist automatically

```
@JsonSerialize(converter = PersistenceBagConverter.class)
private List<SomeObjectType> options;
```

```
public class PersistenceBagConverter<T> extends StdConverter<PersistentBag, Collection<T>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<T> convert(PersistentBag value) {
        return value != null ? new ArrayList<T>(value) : new ArrayList<>();
    }  
}
```

Object mapper looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, classPropertyTypeName);
```